# How to create a certificate signing request with extensions and atributes values in GO?

Tags: go, certificate, csr

I'm trying to use crypto/x509 package to create a certificate request (csr) but I can't figure out how to add extensions and atributes parameters.

In [CertificateRequest struct](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#CertificateRequest) we can see that extensions are pkix.Extension type. This is the structure of [pki.Extension](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/pkix/#Extension):

```golang
type Extension struct {
        Id       asn1.ObjectIdentifier
        Critical bool `asn1:"optional"`
        Value    []byte
}
```

Searching in code I found the following constants in https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/x509.go:

```golang
var (
    oidExtKeyUsageAny                            = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2, 5, 29, 37, 0}
    oidExtKeyUsageServerAuth                     = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 1}
    oidExtKeyUsageClientAuth                     = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 2}
    oidExtKeyUsageCodeSigning                    = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 3}
    oidExtKeyUsageEmailProtection                = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 4}
    oidExtKeyUsageIPSECEndSystem                 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 5}
    oidExtKeyUsageIPSECTunnel                    = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 6}
    oidExtKeyUsageIPSECUser                      = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 7}
    oidExtKeyUsageTimeStamping                   = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 8}
    oidExtKeyUsageOCSPSigning                    = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 9}
    oidExtKeyUsageMicrosoftServerGatedCrypto     = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 311, 10, 3, 3}
    oidExtKeyUsageNetscapeServerGatedCrypto      = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2, 16, 840, 1, 113730, 4, 1}
    oidExtKeyUsageMicrosoftCommercialCodeSigning = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 311, 2, 1, 22}
    oidExtKeyUsageMicrosoftKernelCodeSigning     = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 311, 61, 1, 1}
)
```

Ok, now I have the Id of parameter. In my case, I want to set KeyUsage extension to serverAuth. I have the id but what is the value?

I don't know if I am in the right way. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes field is considered deprecated and it doesn't work properly.

When I had to add attribute to csr, I copied to internal file needed functionality for x509.CreateCertificateRequest and fixed CreateCertificateRequest with adding my attribute in raw format right before marshaling tbsCSR field of certificateRequest. Note: certificateRequest struct is not x509.CertifiacteRequest, that structure is used for marshaling. Here is code example for passwordChallengeAttribute:

```
var oidChallengePassword = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 9, 7}

type passwordChallengeAttribute struct {
    Type  asn1.ObjectIdentifier
    Value []string `asn1:"set"`
}

passwordAttribute := passwordChallengeAttribute{
    Type:  oidChallengePassword,
    Value: []string{challenge},
}

b, err := asn1.Marshal(passwordAttribute)
if err != nil {
    //
}

var rawAttribute asn1.RawValue
asn1.Unmarshal(b, &rawAttribute)
tbsCSR.RawAttributes = append(tbsCSR.RawAttributes, rawAttribute)
```

But working with extensions is better and supported so you only need to implement data structure that represents needed extension, marshal it and add to the list of extensions. For example, adding BasicConstraints extension:

```
type basicConstraints struct {
    IsCA       bool `asn1:"optional"`
    MaxPathLen int  `asn1:"optional,default:-1"`
}   
var extensions []pkix.Extension
basicCon := basicConstraints{IsCA: true, MaxPathLen: -1} 
bitstr, err := asn1.Marshal(basicCon)
if err != nil {
    //  
}   
var oidExtensionBasicConstraints = []int{2, 5, 29, 19} //export from x509 package
bcExt := pkix.Extension{Id: oidExtensionBasicConstraints, Value: bitstr}
extensions = append(extensions, bcExt)
csrTmpl := &x509.CertificateRequest{
    Extensions:    extensions,
}
```